# Active Record field exists in the development DB, but not in the test DB of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm new to rails and I've been trying to create a model test for a Modal: User and test a field birthdate (type: date).

Here is my modal test

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = User.new(firstname: "FirstName", 
      lastname: "LastName",
      birthdate: "11.09.1980".to_date, 
      sex: "Frau",
      username: "username",
      email: "user@test.com",
      password: "password")

  test "Default user is valid"
    assert @user.valid?
  end

end
```

If I run the test, I get the response

> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'birthdate' for User.
>       test/models/user_test.rb:5:in `setup'

I am now really confused. Because if I create the exact same user (copy & past) in my rails console, there is no problem in creating the birthdate and accessing or changing it. Here is what I get after creating the user in rails console

> => #User id: nil, firstname: "FirstName", lastname: "LastName", sex: 0, birthdate: "1980-09-11", username: "username", email: "user@test.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$T/TB..."

I have the following table created as a migration

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string  "firstname"
      t.string  "lastname"
      t.integer "sex"
      t.date    "birthdate"
      t.string  "username"
      t.string  "email"
      t.string  "password_digest"
    end
```

Any good ideas would be highly appreciated. I just can't get my test to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably your development database have birthdate meanwhile your test  database doesn't, you can try to run

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

this to load your current schema to your test database. and try to run test again

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty common that your test database schema is out of sync with development. I have this in my aliases (acronym for 'reset test database'), you may find it useful:

```
alias rtd='bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test'
```